# JSF Property not found exception. porperty not readable

Tags: jsf, cdi, el

can someone help out, I just don't get it, the other bean works fine, i'ts just that bean that sucks:

BEAN:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SessionScoped
@Named
class FeedbackController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Lecture lecture;
    private List<Feedback> filteredFeedbacks;

    public Lecture getLecture() {
        return lecture;
    }

    public void setLecture(Lecture lecture) {
        this.lecture = lecture;
    }
```

VIEW:

```
<p:dataTable var="feedback" 
             value="#{feedbackController.lecture.feedbacks}"
```

ERROR:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.xxx.controller.FeedbackController' does not have a readable property 'lecture'.
```

Since I'm quite nooby to the subject, i dont even know what i'm possibly doing wrong. I dont get, why it is not possible to access 'lecture' when the Controller is @Named and has a public getLecture() method. Also to say, is that i've got another view with the same priciple and it works fine, so i suppose to know what i'm doing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cleaned and rebuild, several times, but thanks for the response =/

Comment: No that wasn't it:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'de.xxx.controller.FeedbackController' does not have a readable property 'lecturetest'.

but i found another exception where it says: does not have a property... the "readable" is missing. mayby it's something whit that?

Comment: The name  is unique, I curently have 2 Named beans (LectureController and FeedbackController) ... and i tried to set the getLecture() method Named too (instead of the whole controller), but it is still not working.

However due to the suffix test, I know now that the problem itself is the readbale. the property is found but it is not readable =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed it:
Must be **public** class FeedbackController implements Serializable {

thanks to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) for helping me out!